# Issue in alternate Row color using each() method of JQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a table as under

```
<table >
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">EmpId</th><th scope="col">EmpName</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td><td>ABC</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td><td>DEF</td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

I want to set the alternate row color of only the "td" elements of the table and not "th" by **using only each()** function. I have tried with

```
<style type="text/css">   
    tr.even { background-color: green; }   
    tr.odd { background-color: yellow; }
</style>
 $(document).ready(function () {
 $('table > tbody').each(function () {
            $('tr:odd',  this).addClass('odd').removeClass('even');
            $('tr:even', this).addClass('even').removeClass('odd');
        });
 });
```

Though this works but it accepts also "th" element. How to avoid that?

Please help

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple fix with css only:

```
<style type="text/css">   
    tr.even td{ background-color: green; }   
    tr.odd td{ background-color: yellow; }
 </style>
```

Answer (score 1):

An easy solution would be to put your `<th>` row inside a `<thead>` and add an explicit `<tbody>`:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">EmpId</th><th scope="col">EmpName</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td><td>ABC</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td><td>DEF</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/bGvA2/

---

If you can't change the HTML to make it sensible, then you could do something like this:

```
$('table tr').not(':first').each(function(i) {
    $(this).addClass(i % 2 ? 'odd' : 'even');
});​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/TGfrF/

Or perhaps:

```
$('table tr').not(':first')
    .filter(':even').addClass('even').end()
    .filter(':odd' ).addClass('odd');
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/GNFaC/

These two do assume that you only have one row of `<th>`s.

​

Comment: Actually I have a GridView in Asp.net. The table structure I placed here is the rendered one.

Comment: @user1323981: I added a couple approaches that should work without changing the HTML.

Answer (score 1):

**Demo:** [**on Jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/nawazhi/jLY9u/)

```
    $('table tr').not(':first')
    .filter(':even').addClass('even').end()
    .filter(':odd' ).addClass('odd');​
    $('table tr:first-child').addClass('head').removeClass('odd');// will style the heading
```

OR

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 $('table > tbody').each(function () {
            $('tr:odd',  this).addClass('odd').removeClass('even');
            $('tr:even', this).addClass('even').removeClass('odd');
        });
    $('table tr:first-child').addClass('head').removeClass('odd'); // will style the heading
 });
```

**Style**:

```
    tr.even { background-color: green; }   
    tr.odd { background-color: yellow; }
    tr.head { background-color: red; }
```